# Code to delete older backups, ordered by date

Tags: bash, shell, date, terminal, backup

I'm very new in bash script and need to write this code.

The purpose of this code is to delete older backups depending on how old they are. The folders name is the date they were made. I think I commented everything, so the idea should be easy to get.

```
#!/bin/sh
#delte backups automatically 

cd backup/backup_collection #make sure to be in the right directory

todate=$(date +”%Y-%m-%d”) #today 

count_back=$(ls -l | grep "^d" | wc -l) #counts the number of folders in the current directory

back_names=( $( ls . ) ) #array with all filenames

for ((i=0; i<count_back; i++ ))
do
    back_days[i]=$(( (todate +%s - todate +%s -d ${back_names[i]}) /86400 ))       #this number tells us how many days ago this backup was
done

#the array with the days is already sorted from small to big

y=$(((${back_days[count_back-1]} + 2) / 7)) #y is the newest date, how many weeks ago

for ((i=count_back-2; i>=0; i—- ))
do
    x=$(((${back_days[i]} + 2) / 7))    #how many weeks ago is the i-th entry

    if [ x<8 ] || [ [ x>=8 ] && [ x<=26 ] && [ y-x>=2 ] ] || [ [ x>=26 ] && [ x<52 ] && [ y-x>=4 ] ] || [ [ x>=52 ] && [ y-x>=8 ] ]
    then
        y=$x
    else
        rmdir backup/backup_collection/${back_names[i]} #we remove the specific folder
    fi


done
```

The code does not work yet. For example this line is not correct I think.

```
back_days[i]=$(( (todate +%s - todate +%s -d ${back_names[i]}) /86400 ))
```

I tried very much. Maybe someone can help me. I would appreciate it!

Comment: You have chosen the most difficult way possible to write a script: finishing it completely and then trying to debug it. This is hard because there are now ~20 instances of ~8 different problems that you're now trying to solve all at the same time. You will find it much easier to write the script line by line, and with each addition running it and making sure everything works as expected. This way, you'll only have 1-2 problems at a time to deal with.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Also see the tests `[ file1 -nt file2 ]` (`file1` is newer then `file2`) and `[ file1 -ot file2 ]` (`file1` is older than `file2`) .

Answer (score 1):

What I'm using is something like that

```
MAXKEEP=30
ZIPPER_EXT="gz"

find $LOG_DIR -type f -name "*.$ZIPPER_EXT" -mtime +$MAXKEEP -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

LOG_DIR is self-explaining, and I do compress (in other part of the script) my files after a certain amount of time so I'm looking for the compressed files only. So, that line do erase compressed file after 30 days. But that can be modified easily to suits your need I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the find command

```
find $RAIZ/ -name "*.gz" -atime +2 -type f -print -exec rm {} \;
```

where $ RAIZ is the directory where they are.
atime is the antiquity time in days and * .gz all extension files .gz
Maybe it's not exactly what you need, but it's a start